# Returning data which at least match 2 attributes in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in Mongodb database as following:

```
db.doc.find({ })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda300b92a26e01f4bc2f"), "name" : "John", "age": 10, "address": "City A", "hobby": "-", "email": "some@email.com", "phone": "085123", "accNo": "09876", "openDate": "2011-04-03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda330b92a26e01f4bc30"), "name" : "Robert", "age": 14, "address": "City B", "hobby": "-", "email": "some@email.com", "phone": "085123", "accNo": "09876", "openDate": "2011-04-03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda3c0b92a26e01f4bc32"), "name" : "Alysa", "age": 10, "address": "City B", "hobby": "-", "email": "some@email.com", "phone": "085123", "accNo": "09876", "openDate": "2011-04-03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda3c0b92a26e01f4bc32"), "name" : "John", "age": 11, "address": "City C", "hobby": "-", "email": "some@email.com", "phone": "085123", "accNo": "09876", "openDate": "2011-04-03" }
```

I want to get list of data that match at least 2 values. For example if I pass some arguments:

```
const args = { name: 'John', age: 10, address: 'City B', hobby: 'playing game', email: 'john@mail.com', phone: '1234', accNo: '1111', openDate: '2010-02-01' }
```

I will get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda300b92a26e01f4bc2f"), "name" : "John", "age": 10, "address": "City A", "hobby": "-", "email": "some@email.com", "phone": "085123", "accNo": "09876", "openDate": "2011-04-03"  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda3c0b92a26e01f4bc32"), "name" : "Alysa", "age": 10, "address": "City B", "hobby": "-", "email": "some@email.com", "phone": "085123", "accNo": "09876", "openDate": "2011-04-03" }
```

My current query is:

```
db.doc.find({"$or":[{"$and":[{"name":"John","age":"10"}]},{"$and":[{"name":"John","address":"City B"}]},{"$and":[{"name":"John","hobby":"N/A"}]},{"$and":[{"name":"John","email":"john@email.com"}]},{"$and":[{"name":"John","phone":"1234"}]},{"$and":[{"name":"John","accNo":"1111"}]},{"$and":[{"name":"John","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]},{"$and":[{"age":"10","address":"City B"}]},{"$and":[{"age":"10","hobby":"N/A"}]},{"$and":[{"age":"10","email":"john@email.com"}]},{"$and":[{"age":"10","phone":"1234"}]},{"$and":[{"age":"10","accNo":"1111"}]},{"$and":[{"age":"10","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]},{"$and":[{"address":"City B","hobby":"N/A"}]},{"$and":[{"address":"City B","email":"john@email.com"}]},{"$and":[{"address":"City B","phone":"1234"}]},{"$and":[{"address":"City B","accNo":"1111"}]},{"$and":[{"address":"City B","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]},{"$and":[{"hobby":"N/A","email":"john@email.com"}]},{"$and":[{"hobby":"N/A","phone":"1234"}]},{"$and":[{"hobby":"N/A","accNo":"1111"}]},{"$and":[{"hobby":"N/A","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]},{"$and":[{"email":"john@email.com","phone":"1234"}]},{"$and":[{"email":"john@email.com","accNo":"1111"}]},{"$and":[{"email":"john@email.com","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]},{"$and":[{"phone":"1234","accNo":"1111"}]},{"$and":[{"phone":"1234","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]},{"$and":[{"accNo":"1111","openDate":"2010-02-01"}]}]})
```

Is there any way I can simplify the query? Thank you

Comment: You can try an `$or` query operator for filtering the data: [MongoDB OR logical operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or).

Comment: I tried. however the real case is I have more args (more than 7 args) to compare so if using $or, it will be really long query.. I wonder if I can use other operator to simplify it..

Comment: Please update the post with what you have tried.

Comment: updated. I have put my query

Comment: I see you have updated the collection data also (the documents have more fields). I think first try to get the query correctly with three arguments and the initial data/fields. Then you can apply to data with more fields and arguments. One of the things you can do is remove the `$and` operator for this `{"name":"John","age":"10"}`; it is same as `$and: ["name":"John","age":"10"]`.